Extending a function to a meromorphic function outside of unit disc
Suppose that $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{D} = \{|z|<1\}$, continuous on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ and $|f(z)| = 1$ for all $|z| = 1$. Show that
(a) $f$ can be extended to a meromorphic function $F$ on $\mathbb{C}$, by defining
$$ F(z) = \Big(\overline{f(1/\overline{z})}\Big)^{-1} \quad \text{for all $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{D}$}.$$
(b)  $F$ is rational and has the form
$$
   F (z) = e^{i \alpha} \prod_{j=1}^N \frac{z - a_j}{1 - \overline{a}_j z}
$$
for some $a_j \in \mathbb{D}$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.
My attempt:
(a) $f$ is holomorphic so $f = \sum a_n (z-z_0)$. Then $f(\frac{1}{\overline{z}}) = \sum a_n (\frac{1}{\overline{z}} - z_0)$, and
$$F(z) = \left(\overline{f\left(\frac{1}{\overline{z}}\right)}\right)^{-1} = \left(\sum \overline{a}_n (\frac{1}{z} - \overline{z}_0)\right)^{-1}$$
So $F(z)$ is not a function of $\overline{z}$ and is thus holomorphic away from 0 except possibly at zeros of $f(\frac{1}{\overline{z}})$.
(b) I am not sure how to show that $F$ is rational and it has this particular form. In particular, I do not see why should all of the zeros be simple.
One thing that comes to mind is that if $F(z)$ and $ \prod_{j=1}^N \frac{z - a_j}{1 - \overline{a}_j z}$ have the same zeros and poles then their ratio must be constant since everything would cancel. The constant would have to be of modulo 1 since on $|z| = 1$ we know that $\left|\prod_{j=1}^N \frac{z - a_j}{1 - \bar{a}_j z}\right| = 1$. One question that bothers me as well is that $e^{i \alpha} \prod_{j=1}^N \frac{z - a_j}{1 - \bar{a}_j z}$ has zeros at $a_j$ but it has poles at $\frac{1}{\overline{a_j}}$. I do not see why zeros and poles should have this relationship.
Also I am looking to prove this using elementary theorems in graduate complex analysis. In particular I am not familiar with results about Blaschke products.

you are almost done as $f(z)=e^{i \alpha} \prod_{j=1}^N \frac{z - a_j}{1 - \bar{a}_j z}$ by your arguments - these are called Finite Blaschke products but you do not need to use this terminology if you do not wish; note that the hypothesis (modulus $1$ on the boundary) implies that $f$ has finitely many zeroes in the unit disc. As for the second question note that the Blaschke products (and their factors) are precisely the ones that have modulus one on the unit circle and that forces the relation between the zeroes and the poles since the unit circle is invariant under $w \to 1/\bar w$
